# OpenCV 3.2.0 cannot access to SURF/SIFT in xfeatures2d

Tags: c++, qt, opencv, sift, cmake-gui

I am using Qt creator in Ubuntu 16.04 to build a non-Qt project. I need to use SIFT to detect features. I know that SIFT and SURF are in OpenCV_contrib so I add the extra module when using Cmake-gui to configure OpenCV.

Then I can find libopencv_xfeatures2d.so/.so.3.2/.so.3.2.0 and also libopencv_features2d.so/.so.3.2/.so.3.2.0 in /usr/local/lib

When I am using the code from OpenCV official website:
[SIFT code from OpenCV official website][1]

to test SIFT, I still get the error

```
/home/ronjane92/Documents/Qt/OpenCV/build/lib/libslam_essentials.so:-1: error: undefined reference to `cv::xfeatures2d::SIFT::create(int, int, double, double, double)'

:-1: error: collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

My **CMakeLists.txt** has the following things:

```
CMAKE_MINIMUM_REQUIRED(VERSION 2.8)
PROJECT(opencv_test)

include( CheckCXXCompilerFlag )
SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-std=c++11 ${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS}")

FIND_PACKAGE( PCL 1.7 REQUIRED COMPONENTS common io visualization)
ADD_DEFINITIONS( ${PCL_DEFINITIONS} )
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES( ${PCL_INCLUDE_DIRS} )
LINK_DIRECTORIES( ${PCL_LIBRARY_DIRS} )

ADD_SUBDIRECTORY(lib)
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES( ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib )
LINK_DIRECTORIES( ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/lib )

FIND_PACKAGE( OpenCV 3.1.0 REQUIRED )
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES( ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS} )

ADD_EXECUTABLE(${PROJECT_NAME} "main.cpp")
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(opencv_test ${OpenCV_LIBRARIES}
                                  ${PCL_LIBRARIES}
                                  realsense
                                  slam_essentials
                     )
```

The results from Cmake-gui are

```
Detected version of GNU GCC: 54 (504)
FP16: Feature disabled
Found ZLIB: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so (found suitable version "1.2.8", minimum required is "1.2.3") 
Found ZLIB: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so (found version "1.2.8") 
Found OpenEXR: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libIlmImf.so
Checking for module 'gstreamer-base-1.0'
  No package 'gstreamer-base-1.0' found
Checking for module 'gstreamer-video-1.0'
  No package 'gstreamer-video-1.0' found
Checking for module 'gstreamer-app-1.0'
  No package 'gstreamer-app-1.0' found
Checking for module 'gstreamer-riff-1.0'
  No package 'gstreamer-riff-1.0' found
Checking for module 'gstreamer-pbutils-1.0'
  No package 'gstreamer-pbutils-1.0' found
Checking for module 'gstreamer-base-0.10'
  No package 'gstreamer-base-0.10' found
Checking for module 'gstreamer-video-0.10'
  No package 'gstreamer-video-0.10' found
Checking for module 'gstreamer-app-0.10'
  No package 'gstreamer-app-0.10' found
Checking for module 'gstreamer-riff-0.10'
  No package 'gstreamer-riff-0.10' found
Checking for module 'gstreamer-pbutils-0.10'
  No package 'gstreamer-pbutils-0.10' found
Looking for linux/videodev.h
Looking for linux/videodev.h - not found
Looking for linux/videodev2.h
Looking for linux/videodev2.h - found
Looking for sys/videoio.h
Looking for sys/videoio.h - not found
WARNING, PrimeSensor Module binaries directory (set by OPENNI_PRIME_SENSOR_MODULE_BIN_DIR variable) is not found or does not have PrimeSensor Module binaries.
Checking for module 'libavresample'
  No package 'libavresample' found
Checking for module 'libgphoto2'
  No package 'libgphoto2' found
Found TBB: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtbb.so
found IPP (ICV version): 9.0.1 [9.0.1]
at: /home/ronjane92/Programs/opencv/opencv-3.2.0-build/3rdparty/ippicv/ippicv_lnx
Could not find OpenBLAS lib. Turning OpenBLAS_FOUND off
Could NOT find Atlas (missing:  Atlas_CLAPACK_INCLUDE_DIR) 
Could NOT find JNI (missing:  JAVA_INCLUDE_PATH JAVA_INCLUDE_PATH2 JAVA_AWT_INCLUDE_PATH) 
Could NOT find Matlab (missing:  MATLAB_MEX_SCRIPT MATLAB_INCLUDE_DIRS MATLAB_ROOT_DIR MATLAB_LIBRARIES MATLAB_LIBRARY_DIRS MATLAB_MEXEXT MATLAB_ARCH MATLAB_BIN) 
The imported target "vtkRenderingPythonTkWidgets" references the file
   "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvtkRenderingPythonTkWidgets.so"
but this file does not exist.  Possible reasons include:
* The file was deleted, renamed, or moved to another location.
* An install or uninstall procedure did not complete successfully.
* The installation package was faulty and contained
   "/usr/lib/cmake/vtk-6.2/VTKTargets.cmake"
but not all the files it references.

The imported target "vtk" references the file
   "/usr/bin/vtk"
but this file does not exist.  Possible reasons include:
* The file was deleted, renamed, or moved to another location.
* An install or uninstall procedure did not complete successfully.
* The installation package was faulty and contained
   "/usr/lib/cmake/vtk-6.2/VTKTargets.cmake"
but not all the files it references.

Found VTK ver. 6.2.0 (usefile: /usr/lib/cmake/vtk-6.2/UseVTK.cmake)
Caffe:   NO
Protobuf:   YES
Glog:   NO
freetype2:   YES
harfbuzz:    YES
Module opencv_sfm disabled because the following dependencies are not found: Glog/Gflags
freetype2:   YES
harfbuzz:    YES
Checking for modules 'tesseract;lept'
  No package 'tesseract' found
  No package 'lept' found
Tesseract:   NO
Check contents of vgg_generated_48.i ...
Check contents of vgg_generated_64.i ...
Check contents of vgg_generated_80.i ...
Check contents of vgg_generated_120.i ...
Check contents of boostdesc_bgm.i ...
Check contents of boostdesc_bgm_bi.i ...
Check contents of boostdesc_bgm_hd.i ...
Check contents of boostdesc_binboost_064.i ...
Check contents of boostdesc_binboost_128.i ...
Check contents of boostdesc_binboost_256.i ...
Check contents of boostdesc_lbgm.i ...

General configuration for OpenCV 3.2.0 =====================================
  Version control:               unknown

  Extra modules:
    Location (extra):            /home/ronjane92/Programs/opencv/opencv_contrib-3.2.0/modules
    Version control (extra):     unknown

  Platform:
    Timestamp:                   2017-09-16T18:20:02Z
    Host:                        Linux 4.8.0-58-generic x86_64
    CMake:                       3.5.1
    CMake generator:             Unix Makefiles
    CMake build tool:            /usr/bin/make
    Configuration:               Release

  C/C++:
    Built as dynamic libs?:      YES
    C++ Compiler:                /usr/bin/c++  (ver 5.4.0)
    C++ flags (Release):         -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wsign-promo -Wno-narrowing -Wno-delete-non-virtual-dtor -Wno-comment -fdiagnostics-show-option -Wno-long-long -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -msse -msse2 -mno-avx -msse3 -mno-ssse3 -mno-sse4.1 -mno-sse4.2 -ffunction-sections -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -O3 -DNDEBUG  -DNDEBUG
    C++ flags (Debug):           -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wsign-promo -Wno-narrowing -Wno-delete-non-virtual-dtor -Wno-comment -fdiagnostics-show-option -Wno-long-long -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -msse -msse2 -mno-avx -msse3 -mno-ssse3 -mno-sse4.1 -mno-sse4.2 -ffunction-sections -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -g  -O0 -DDEBUG -D_DEBUG
    C Compiler:                  /usr/bin/cc
    C flags (Release):           -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wno-narrowing -Wno-comment -fdiagnostics-show-option -Wno-long-long -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -msse -msse2 -mno-avx -msse3 -mno-ssse3 -mno-sse4.1 -mno-sse4.2 -ffunction-sections -fvisibility=hidden -O3 -DNDEBUG  -DNDEBUG
    C flags (Debug):             -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wno-narrowing -Wno-comment -fdiagnostics-show-option -Wno-long-long -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -msse -msse2 -mno-avx -msse3 -mno-ssse3 -mno-sse4.1 -mno-sse4.2 -ffunction-sections -fvisibility=hidden -g  -O0 -DDEBUG -D_DEBUG
    Linker flags (Release):
    Linker flags (Debug):
    ccache:                      NO
    Precompiled headers:         YES
    Extra dependencies:          Qt5::Test Qt5::Concurrent Qt5::OpenGL /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwebp.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjasper.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libImath.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libIlmImf.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libIex.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libHalf.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libIlmThread.so dc1394 avcodec-ffmpeg avformat-ffmpeg avutil-ffmpeg swscale-ffmpeg /usr/lib/libOpenNI.so Qt5::Core Qt5::Gui Qt5::Widgets /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/hdf5/serial/lib/libhdf5.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsz.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so vtkRenderingOpenGL vtkImagingHybrid vtkIOImage vtkCommonDataModel vtkCommonMath vtkCommonCore vtksys vtkCommonMisc vtkCommonSystem vtkCommonTransforms vtkCommonExecutionModel vtkDICOMParser vtkIOCore /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so vtkmetaio /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtiff.so vtkImagingCore vtkRenderingCore vtkCommonColor vtkFiltersExtraction vtkFiltersCore vtkFiltersGeneral vtkCommonComputationalGeometry vtkFiltersStatistics vtkImagingFourier vtkalglib vtkFiltersGeometry vtkFiltersSources vtkInteractionStyle vtkRenderingLOD vtkFiltersModeling vtkIOPLY vtkIOGeometry /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjsoncpp.so vtkFiltersTexture vtkRenderingFreeType /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfreetype.so vtkftgl vtkIOExport vtkRenderingAnnotation vtkImagingColor vtkRenderingContext2D vtkRenderingGL2PS vtkRenderingContextOpenGL /usr/lib/libgl2ps.so vtkRenderingLabel dl m pthread rt /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLU.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so tbb
    3rdparty dependencies:       libprotobuf

  OpenCV modules:
    To be built:                 core flann hdf imgproc ml photo reg surface_matching video viz dnn freetype fuzzy imgcodecs shape videoio highgui objdetect plot superres ts xobjdetect xphoto bgsegm bioinspired dpm face features2d line_descriptor saliency text calib3d ccalib cvv datasets rgbd stereo tracking videostab xfeatures2d ximgproc aruco optflow phase_unwrapping stitching structured_light python2
    Disabled:                    world contrib_world
    Disabled by dependency:      -
    Unavailable:                 cudaarithm cudabgsegm cudacodec cudafeatures2d cudafilters cudaimgproc cudalegacy cudaobjdetect cudaoptflow cudastereo cudawarping cudev java python3 cnn_3dobj matlab sfm

  Non-free algorithms are enabled

  GUI: 
    QT 5.x:                      YES (ver 5.5.1)
    QT OpenGL support:           YES (Qt5::OpenGL 5.5.1)
    OpenGL support:              YES (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLU.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so)
    VTK support:                 YES (ver 6.2.0)

  Media I/O: 
    ZLib:                        /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so (ver 1.2.8)
    JPEG:                        /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so (ver )
    WEBP:                        /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwebp.so (ver encoder: 0x0202)
    PNG:                         /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng.so (ver 1.2.54)
    TIFF:                        /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtiff.so (ver 42 - 4.0.6)
    JPEG 2000:                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjasper.so (ver 1.900.1)
    OpenEXR:                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libImath.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libIlmImf.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libIex.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libHalf.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libIlmThread.so (ver 2.2.0)
    GDAL:                        NO
    GDCM:                        NO

  Video I/O:
    DC1394 1.x:                  NO
    DC1394 2.x:                  YES (ver 2.2.4)
    FFMPEG:                      YES
      avcodec:                   YES (ver 56.60.100)
      avformat:                  YES (ver 56.40.101)
      avutil:                    YES (ver 54.31.100)
      swscale:                   YES (ver 3.1.101)
      avresample:                NO
    GStreamer:                   NO
    OpenNI:                      YES (ver 1.5.4, build 0)
    OpenNI PrimeSensor Modules:  NO
    OpenNI2:                     NO
    PvAPI:                       NO
    GigEVisionSDK:               NO
    Aravis SDK:                  NO
    UniCap:                      NO
    UniCap ucil:                 NO
    V4L/V4L2:                    NO/YES
    XIMEA:                       NO
    Xine:                        NO
    gPhoto2:                     NO

  Parallel framework:            TBB (ver 4.4 interface 9002)

  Other third-party libraries:
    Use IPP:                     9.0.1 [9.0.1]
         at:                     /home/ronjane92/Programs/opencv/opencv-3.2.0-build/3rdparty/ippicv/ippicv_lnx
    Use IPP Async:               NO
    Use VA:                      NO
    Use Intel VA-API/OpenCL:     NO
    Use Lapack:                  NO
    Use Eigen:                   YES (ver 3.2.92)
    Use Cuda:                    NO
    Use OpenCL:                  YES
    Use OpenVX:                  NO
    Use custom HAL:              NO

  OpenCL:                        <Dynamic loading of OpenCL library>
    Include path:                /home/ronjane92/Programs/opencv/opencv-3.2.0-source/3rdparty/include/opencl/1.2
    Use AMDFFT:                  NO
    Use AMDBLAS:                 NO

  Python 2:
    Interpreter:                 /usr/bin/python2.7 (ver 2.7.12)
    Libraries:                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython2.7.so (ver 2.7.12)
    numpy:                       /home/ronjane92/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include (ver 1.13.1)
    packages path:               lib/python2.7/dist-packages

  Python 3:
    Interpreter:                 /usr/bin/python3 (ver 3.5.2)

  Python (for build):            /usr/bin/python2.7

  Java:
    ant:                         NO
    JNI:                         NO
    Java wrappers:               NO
    Java tests:                  NO

  Matlab:                        Matlab not found or implicitly disabled

  Documentation:
    Doxygen:                     /usr/bin/doxygen (ver 1.8.11)

  Tests and samples:
    Tests:                       YES
    Performance tests:           YES
    C/C++ Examples:              NO

  Install path:                  /usr/local

  cvconfig.h is in:              /home/ronjane92/Programs/opencv/opencv-3.2.0-build
-----------------------------------------------------------------

Configuring done
Generating done
```

This is a repeated question so I've tried to google for solutions but none of them worked in my situation. Anyone who can help me out? Thanks.

Comment: The issue is more likely about the way OpenCV should be built: http://answers.opencv.org/question/52001/how-to-compile-nonfree-module-in-opencv-30-beta/

Answer (score 2):

Problem solved. I defined some functions and those functions need to link to OpenCV libraries. However, I just add FIND_PACKAGE and INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES to OpenCV in the CMakeLists.txt in the source directory but in that in the directory where the headers and sources are placed. Everything goes fine after adding to the lib directory.

See [The solution](http://answers.opencv.org/question/174474/opencv-320-cannnot-access-to-surfsift-in-xfeatures2d/)